# PHP Sentry How start tracking http client errors

Tags: php, laravel

There is an option to track client http errors in .Net (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/dotnet/guides/aspnet/configuration/http-client-errors). Couldn't find one for php-laravel. Is there such an option?

Tried searching (https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/php/guides/laravel). Couldn't find one. The closest I could get is

```
'breadcrumbs' => [
    // Capture HTTP client requests information in breadcrumbs
    'http_client_requests' => true,
],
```

As I understand it specifies how much information is logged, but doesn't turn on logging of client https errors.